# Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded. [Rcmdr]

Tags: r, r-commander

i try install R Commander from RGui. i install Rcmdr package so:

Packages -> install packages.

When i Write:

Library(Rcmdr)

R show this error:

[image]

How i can Solve this error?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Read error messages. It usually wise to fix the first one and seems pretty obvious what should be done.

Comment: The first error says: "there is no package Rcpp". Try installing the Rcpp package manually first and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reco,

Try the following:

1. Launch RGui (64)
2. Select Packages from the Menu
3. Select "Select CRAN Mirror...

   - 3.1 Select "0-Cloud [https]
4. Select Install Packages

   - 4.1 Select Rcmdr
5. Select Install Packages

   - 5.1 Select Rcmdrmisc
6. require(Rcmdr)

**Note:** _My personal recommendation is to install RStudio.

[image]

[image]